# Why was "The Lord of the Rings" named as such?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

[From the Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lord_of_the_Rings):

> The title of the novel refers to the story's main antagonist, the Dark Lord Sauron

Is the title implies that the book is really about Sauron, not the fellowship that defeated him? It's strange, don't you think? It's like if the Harry Potter book series were named "He-Who-Must-Not-Be-Named" or "The Dark Lord".

Comment: This issue has now been raised on the Wikipedia [Talk page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:The_Lord_of_the_Rings), with a user saying the article should explain this oddity.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The full title, given in the last chapter, is:

> THE DOWNFALL OF THE LORD OF THE RINGS AND THE RETURN OF THE KING
>
> (as seen by the Little People; being the memoirs of Bilbo and Frodo of the Shire, supplemented by the accounts of their friends and the learning of the Wise.)
>
> Together with extracts from Books of Lore translated by Bilbo in Rivendell.

There's nothing really strange about it; snarkily, one might say that it's as if *The mysterious case of Ellen Ripley* was actually called *Alien*, or as if *Sarah Connor and what she got up to next* was actually called *Terminator*; in other words, **it is actually quite common, and should not be seen as surprising, for a work to be named after the antagonist**.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Actually now I like your improvised titles for Alien and Terminator more than originals.

Comment: Another example nearer to Tolkien's time is *Dracula*.

Comment: Sauron is the sole driving force behind the entire plot of the series, it makes perfect sense to name the series after him. Also, note that the individual books *do* have other names, only one of them referencing Sauron.

Comment: [Do not click this TVTropes link.](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AntagonistTitle)

Comment: @Darth: just because historical time compression/dilation is fun, actually *Alien* (1979) is considerably closer to the publishing date of *LOTR* (1954) than is *Dracula* (1897). It's slightly further from when Tolkien started writing it though (1937). But Tolkien was alive when *Dracula* was published and not *Alien* so sure, his time, you can certainly have that :-)

Comment: @leftaroundabout I failed to not click the link and lost three days of my life :D

Comment: Now I want to go rewatch *Sarah Conner and What She Got Up To Next*.

Comment: It seems wrong to assume that the title of the Red Book is the full title of Tolkien’s work, or the title under which he wished to publish it,